# print matrix with indicies python

Tags: python, printing, matrix

I have a matrix in Python defined like this:

```
matrix = [['A']*4 for i in range(4)]
```

How do I print it in the following format:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  A  A  A  A
1  A  A  A  A
2  A  A  A  A
3  A  A  A  A
```

Comment: homework? At least try it out and post your progress so far.

Comment: Your code produces a 4x4 Matrix, whereas you give an example of a 3x3 Matrix.

Comment: @SukritKalra you are right of course :) I have edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function matches your exact output.

```
>>> def printMatrix(testMatrix):
        print ' ',
        for i in range(len(testMatrix[1])):  # Make it work with non square matrices.
              print i,
        print
        for i, element in enumerate(testMatrix):
              print i, ' '.join(element)
>>> matrix = [['A']*4 for i in range(4)]
>>> printMatrix(matrix)
  0 1 2 3
0 A A A A
1 A A A A
2 A A A A
3 A A A A
>>> matrix = [['A']*6 for i in range(4)]
>>> printMatrix(matrix)
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 A A A A A A
1 A A A A A A
2 A A A A A A
3 A A A A A A
```

To check for single length elements and put an `&` in place of elements with length > 1, you could put a check in the list comprehension, the code would change as follows.

```
>>> def printMatrix2(testMatrix):
    print ' ',
    for i in range(len(testmatrix[1])):
        print i,
    print
    for i, element in enumerate(testMatrix):
        print i, ' '.join([elem if len(elem) == 1 else '&' for elem in element])
>>> matrix = [['A']*6 for i in range(4)]
>>> matrix[1][1] = 'AB'
>>> printMatrix(matrix)
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 A A A A A A
1 A AB A A A A
2 A A A A A A
3 A A A A A A
>>> printMatrix2(matrix)
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 A A A A A A
1 A & A A A A
2 A A A A A A
3 A A A A A A
```

Comment: Thanks! If I want to check each cell content before writing it how would the second for loop would changed? let's say that if in some cell I have more than one letter I want to print some special character.

Comment: If I get your question correctly, you mean, for example you have a matrix of `A` with `AB` in position `(1,1)` and want to print a `&` in place of that `AB` instead of printing `AB`. Please see the Edited answer for such a code.

Comment: Small fix -> changed testMatrix to testmatrix at the function signature.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
...     print i, ' '.join(row)
...
0 A A A A
1 A A A A
2 A A A A
3 A A A A
```

I guess you'll find out how to print out the first line :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
>>> matrix = [['A'] * 4 for i in range(4)]
>>> def solve(mat):
    print " ", " ".join([str(x) for x in xrange(len(mat))])
    for i, x in enumerate(mat):
        print i, " ".join(x)  # or " ".join([str(y) for y in x]) if elements are not string
...         
>>> solve(matrix)
  0 1 2 3
0 A A A A
1 A A A A
2 A A A A
3 A A A A
>>> matrix = [['A'] * 5 for i in range(5)]
>>> solve(matrix)
  0 1 2 3 4
0 A A A A A
1 A A A A A
2 A A A A A
3 A A A A A
4 A A A A A
```

Comment: You could generalise for all the matrices. Also, looks like OP changed the design in which he wants the printing to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas` for showing any matrix with indices:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(matrix)
   0  1  2  3
0  A  A  A  A
1  A  A  A  A
2  A  A  A  A
3  A  A  A  A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[["A" for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]

for i in range(len(a)):
  print()
  for j in a[i]:
     print("%c "%j,end='')
```

it will print like this:

```
A A A A
A A A A
A A A A
A A A A
```