# How to get python to return a list of lists as a column matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm in an intro course and I have an assignment where I have to essentially create a multiplication table  that I'll call function `make_x_table (r,c):`, that needs to yield this result:

```
make_x_table(3,4):
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 4, 6, 8],
 [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

My problem is that I can't just use the print function to print the individual lists, which I had originally done here in what I'll call `make_x_table_wrong (r,c):`:

```
def make_x_table_wrong (r,c):
    for rownum in range(1, r+1):
        list_v = []
        for colnum in range(1, c+1):
            v = colnum*rownum
            list_v.append(v)
        print (list_v)
```

I need to be able to return the list of lists as a column matrix. Any help on how?

Comment: `[[i*j for i in range(1,c+1)] for j in range(1,r+1)]`

Comment: For m.wasowski, I want it to return as a column matrix, not print it. I know how to do that. And for alfasin, that's actually a very nice way to shorten my former code, but I'm not sure how that allows me to return it as a column matrix. Is it even possible?

Comment: Also, don't forget to mark the helpful answer as correct and upvote it. Welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: define "column matrix"

Comment: Sorry, I saw the terminology somewhere else and I thought I should use it. Basically I want it each list within the list to appear on its own line, like I showed in the result I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code sample, above `for rownum in range(1, r+1):` place `buff = []` so that:

```
buff = []
for rownum in range(1, r+1):
```

Then, where you have `print(list_v)` do the following:

```
buff.append(list_v)
```

Then your code sample will look like

```
def make_x_table_right (r,c):
   buff = []
    for rownum in range(1, r+1):
        list_v = []
        for colnum in range(1, c+1):
            v = colnum*rownum
            list_v.append(v)
        buff.append(list_v)
    return buff
```

Make sense?

Also, since your multiplication table is probably going to be square, I'd suggest just passing one parameter `n` and using `n` in place of `r` and `c`. One other thing, the list comprehension that another user posted as a one-liner comment is perfectly fine, too. Also, it's convention to use variables `i` and `j` for matrix loop identifiers. so instead of `rownum` you'd say `i` and `colnum` you'd say `j`.

Comment: Yup, I thought his shorter method was really cool. But is it possible to actually return the list of lists in a column format? I can generate the horizontal list of lists easy.....

Comment: It is returning a list in a 2d format. I think what you're talking about is a print format function or something. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Check this [link on formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541973/print-matrix-with-indicies-python) and that will solve your printing problem.

So then you can just pass your matrix to that print function and print out the matrix, like so: `some_print_function(make_x_table_right(r,c))`

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what my professor wants. I can get the function to print vertically in the shell, but the way my professor worded things in the assignment made it sound like when I run my module the shell should generate the list of lists as a column of lists just using the return function. I'm starting to think that's not possible?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what your professor wants from you. Show him what you've got in the matrix table function thus so far and see what he says about that, because as it stands right now, which what's going on with that double `[[` thing is all about, it is indeed returning a list of lists, I believe. Unless he wants you to do it the other way and contain the columns as rows instead of lists. In the case that he wants the transpose of what you have the matrix function returning now, just `zip(*make_x_table_right(r,c))`, and that will take the columns and turn them into rows. Better?